# How to create multiple relationships to the same filed in prisma

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

Here Is the related portion of my datamodel.prisma file.

```
type Driver {
  id: ID! @unique
  zones: [Zone!] @relation(name: "DriverZones")
  shifts: [Shift!] @relation(name: "DriverShifts")
  preferredZone: Zone
  preferredShift: Shift
}


type Shift {
  id: ID! @unique 
  drivers: [Driver! ] @relation(name: "DriverShifts") 
}


type Zone {
  id: ID! @unique 
  drivers: [Driver! ] @relation(name: "DriverZones") 
}
```

Here I want to create the relationship for preferredZone and preferredShift to be type Zone and Shift according to the datamodel I have created. 
this is a one way relationship.

The relation field `preferredShift` must specify a `@relation` directive: `@relation(name: "MyRelation")`
    , The relation field `preferredZone` must specify a `@relation` directive: `@relation(name: "MyRelation")`

I'm using PostgreSQL for my prisma database. How to build the relationship between preferredZone to Zone. and preferredShift to Shift.

Answer (score 8):

You need to name the relations since you have two relations between same types (Driver <-> Shift and Driver <-> Zone both are connected by two relations each).

In cases like this Prisma asks you to name the relations which is what the error message you posted is about. I think this data model should work:

```
type Driver {
  id: ID! @unique
  zones: [Zone!] @relation(name: "DriverZones")
  shifts: [Shift!] @relation(name: "DriverShifts")
  preferredZone: Zone @relation(name: "PreferredZone")
  preferredShift: Shift @relation(name: "PreferredShift")
}


type Shift {
  id: ID! @unique 
  drivers: [Driver! ] @relation(name: "DriverShifts") 
}


type Zone {
  id: ID! @unique 
  drivers: [Driver! ] @relation(name: "DriverZones") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to try this way:

```
model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accountId     String    @unique

  account Account @relation(fields: [accountId], references: [id])

  sessions       Session[]
  TeamHasMembers TeamHasMembers[]
  TeamHasLeaders TeamHasLeaders[]
}

model Team {
  id   String @id @default(cuid())
  name String
  slug String @unique

  TeamHasMembers TeamHasMembers[]
  TeamHasLeaders TeamHasLeaders[]
}

model TeamHasMembers {
  id     String @id @default(cuid())
  userId String
  teamId String
  role   String

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  team Team @relation(fields: [teamId], references: [id])
}

model TeamHasLeaders {
  id     String @id @default(cuid())
  userId String
  teamId String

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  team Team @relation(fields: [teamId], references: [id])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This section](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-schema/data-model/relations#disambiguating-relations) from prisma docs is relevant here:

> When you define two relations between the same two models, you need to add the `name` argument in the `@relation` attribute to disambiguate them. As an example for why that's needed, consider the following models:
>
> ```
> // NOTE: This schema is intentionally incorrect. See below for a working solution.
>
> model User {
>   id           Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
>   name         String?
>   writtenPosts Post[]
>   pinnedPost   Post?
> }
>
> model Post {
>   id         Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
>   title      String?
>   author     User    @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
>   authorId   Int
>   pinnedBy   User?   @relation(fields: [pinnedById], references: [id])
>   pinnedById Int?
> }
> ```
>
> In that case, the relations are ambiguous, there are four different ways to interpret them:
>
> - `User.writtenPosts` ↔ `Post.author` + `Post.authorId`
> - `User.writtenPosts` ↔ `Post.pinnedBy` + `Post.pinnedById`
> - `User.pinnedPost` ↔ `Post.author` + `Post.authorId`
> - `User.pinnedPost` ↔ `Post.pinnedBy` + `Post.pinnedById`
>
> To disambiguate these relations, you need to annotate the relation fields with the `@relation` attribute and provide the `name` argument. You can set any `name` (except for the empty string `""`), but it must be the same on both sides of the relation:
>
> ```
> model User {
>   id           Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
>   name         String?
>   writtenPosts Post[]  @relation("WrittenPosts")
>   pinnedPost   Post?   @relation("PinnedPost")
> }
>
> model Post {
>   id         Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
>   title      String?
>   author     User    @relation("WrittenPosts", fields: [authorId], references: [id])
>   authorId   Int
>   pinnedBy   User?   @relation("PinnedPost", fields: [pinnedById], references: [id])
>   pinnedById Int?    @unique
> }
> ```