# Can two fields reference the same field on another model

Tags: prisma

I have two models in my prisma schema for representing a sort of game schedule where 2 "players" can play against each other in a "matchup":

```
model Matchup {
  id             Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  homePlayer     Player @relation("Home Player", fields: [homePlayerId], references: [id])
  homePlayerId   Int
  awayPlayer     Player @relation("Away Player", fields: [awayPlayerId], references: [id])
  awayPlayerId   Int
}

model Player {
  id            Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  homeMatchUps  Matchup[] @relation("Home Player")
  awayMatchUps  Matchup[] @relation("Away Player")
}
```

I don't necessarily need to have the distinction of a "home" player and an "away" player however. I'd rather that the Player model have a single reference to any matchup they were associated with, as opposed to having to split it between two fields.

What would be the correct way to approach this?

Comment: This might be a similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061483/how-to-create-multiple-relationships-to-the-same-filed-in-prisma?rq=1

Comment: Hey, It's not possible to do what you're requesting here.

Comment: @TasinIshmam thanks for letting me know - this seems to validate what I've come to realize as I've done more research today. I suppose that if I'm ever (for example) listing all matchups for a specific player on the "front end", I'll just need to search over both fields. (Feel free to put this comment as an answer by the way and I'll mark it as accepted.)

Comment: Sure, wrote up an anwer. And yes, I would also recommend just querying both relation fields (and merging them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have a single reference to `Matchup` from the `Player` side, you need to have two. So what you're asking for can't really be done.

The reason is, `homePlayer` and `awayPlayer` represent two separate `one-to-many` relations and you need to have a matching field in the many side (in this case `Player`) for every single `one-to-many` relation.